# finding number of records without using count in MYSQL

Tags: mysql, count

So, say I am doing something like Finding the first and last name of all employees that work on more than 1 project.  I know the easiest way to do this is with COUNT, like so....

```
SELECT e.Fname, e.Lname
FROM employee e INNER JOIN works_on w
ON e.SSN = w.ESSN 
GROUP BY SSN
HAVING COUNT(*) > 1
```

This gets me what I need, but someone I was helping asked me how this could be done without using COUNT....and I have no idea.  So, I thought I'd ask here for any pointers or suggestions, because I am dry on this.  For reference, a quick look at the used database is below.  Any help or guidance people can provide would be greatly appreciated.

[image]

Comment: *"more than one"* involves counting, so I wouldn't complicate things. That said, you could join twice on `works_on`, make sure both are different, and see whether the second one is not null.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just a different way of writing similar query to Armin and recommendation from Kenney.

```
create table employee(ssn int, fname varchar(50), lname varchar(50));
create table works_on (essn int, pno int);

insert into employee values (1, 'Tom', 'Smith'), (2, 'Matt', 'Smith'), (3, 'Sam', 'Smith');
insert into works_on values (1, 1), (2, 1), (2, 2), (3, 1), (3, 2);

select distinct fname, lname
from employee e
inner join works_on w1 on e.ssn = w1.essn
where exists (
  select 1 from works_on where essn = e.ssn and pno <> w1.pno
);

Result:
| fname | lname |
|-------|-------|
|  Matt | Smith |
|   Sam | Smith |
```

Example: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/e2411/5

I prefer the `count` method you have, though.

Comment: Thank you, this one works (and makes the most sense to me).  And yeah, I know COUNT is the best and easy way to do it, I just hate hitting a wall in something when asked a question.  Thanks everyone.

Answer (score 1):

As the comment above already points out, you can just join twice if you absolute want to avoid COUNT like this:

```
SELECT e.Fname, e.Lname
FROM employee e 
INNER JOIN works_on w
  ON e.SSN = w.ESSN 
INNER JOIN works_on wd
  ON wd.PNO != w.PNO
GROUP BY SSN
```

Will only get you those that have a least 2 rows in works_on, otherwise the double join fails :)